# How to we prove if a right linear language is ambiguous?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, linear-bounded-automata

Considering the following language as an example:

$$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow aS \mid bA \\
A &\rightarrow bA \mid aB \mid aD \mid \varepsilon \\
B &\rightarrow aB \mid \varepsilon \\
D &\rightarrow aD \mid \varepsilon
\end{align}$$

This has ambiguous transitions on the string $ba$, but how do we prove in general that a right linear language is ambiguous. Is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: All right linear languages are regular, so they are all unambiguous. Do you mean to ask how to prove whether a right linear *grammar* is ambiguous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, let me assume that the only allowed rules are of the form $A \to aB$ and $A \to \epsilon$. Denote the set of nonterminals by $V$, where $S \in V$ is the starting symbol.

Construct a new right linear grammar with nonterminals $V \times V \times \{0,1\}$. The new grammar will simulate two different production sequences for each word, keeping track whether the two actually differ.
The starting symbol is $(S,S,0)$, and the rules are:

- For every pair of original rules $A \to aB$ and $C \to aD$ we add the rule $(A,C,1) \to a(B,D,1)$. (Possibly some of $A,B,C,D$ are equal.)
- For every pair of original rules $A \to aB$ and $A \to aC$ such that $B \neq C$ we add the rule $(A,A,0) \to a(B,C,1)$. (Possibly $A=B$ or $A=C$.)
- For every pair of original rules $A \to \epsilon$ and $B \to \epsilon$ we add the rule $(A,B,1) \to \epsilon$. (Possibly $A=B$.)

A word $w$ has two different derivations in the original grammar iff it can be generated by the new one.

For example, in your sample grammar the word $ba$ has two different derivations, $S \to bA \to baB \to ba$ and $S \to bA \to baD \to ba$, and this is reflected in the following derivation in the new grammar:
$$
(S,S,0) \to b(A,A,0) \to ba(B,D,1) \to ba.
$$

Comment: Nice, what is the time+space complexity of this algorithm.

Comment: That’s a nice question for you to ponder.

Answer (score 2):

A right linear grammar with rules of the form $A\to aB$ and $A\to\varepsilon$ is a finite state automaton in disguise.

Such a linear grammar is ambiguous iff the following holds:

There is a pair of productions $A\to aB$ and $A\to aC$ ($B\neq C$) such that $A$ is reachable from $S$, and the languages derivable from $B$ and $C$ have a string in common.

How do we check whether pairs $B,C$ generate a common string? This can be done by a recursive marking algorithm. We start by marking pairs $(B,C)$ such that $B\to \varepsilon$ and $C\to \varepsilon$ (including $B=C$). Now repeatedly mark pairs $(X,Y)$ for which there are productions $X\to a B$ and $Y\to aC$ with $(B,C)$ marked.

Comment: Yes, this may seem different, but basically this is the same solution as given by Yuval.